# Calling SQL Server stored procedure from Java with R2DBC

Tags: stored-procedures, reactive-programming, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc-mssql

I have a stored procedure which has 2 parameters. An input `NVARCHAR` and an output parameter `int`. That stored procedure is just writing a string into a table. It's a procedure for testing out some tech. I try to call it from Java with R2DBC. I used the `Connection.createStatement` and the `DatabaseClient` approaches as well. None of them really worked out.

Here is an example of my java code using the `DatabaseClient`. It's just a sample which is good for a proof of concept that I can call a stored procedure.

```
      public int callProcedureWithDatabaseClient() {
        databaseClient.sql("CALL MY_SCHEMA.MY_PROCEDURE(Prm1, @Prm2)")
            .bind("Prm1", "Some text to save in database")
            .fetch()
            .all()
            .doOnNext(stringObjectMap -> log.info("{}" + stringObjectMap))
            .subscribe();
    
        return 0;
      }
```

After calling this method I get this error:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Parameter [Prm1] does not exist in query [CALL MY_SCHEMA.MY_PROCEDURE(Prm1, @Prm2)]
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Parameter [Prm1] does not exist in query [CALL MY_SCHEMA.MY_PROCEDURE(Prm1, @Prm2)]
```

I think the syntax is not really correct. I tried more ways, more syntaxes, but there was always an issue. Also tried without the schema, did not worked.

- Do you have any idea how can I make it work?
- The second question is if I can make it work, how can I get the
  value of the output variable `Prm2`?

Alternatively, here is a sample code for the `connection` based call. If the one above can't be fixed, but this one can, than it is also OK:

```
 public int callProcedureWithConnection() {
    ConnectionFactoryUtils.getConnection(connectionFactory)
        .flatMapMany(connection -> connection.createStatement("CALL MY_SCHEMA.MY_PROCEDURE(:Prm1, @Prm2)")
              .bind(":Prm1", Parameters.in(R2dbcType.NVARCHAR, "bacabacabacabacabacn"))
              .bind("@Prm2", Parameters.out(R2dbcType.INTEGER))
            .execute())
        .flatMap(result -> {
          return result.map((row, rowMetadata) -> {
            log.info("{}", row);
            return row.get(0);
          });
        })
        .subscribe();
    return 0;
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks you!

Comment: Not sure about Java but your parameters have different syntax, one has an @ and the other does not:  MY_PROCEDURE(Prm1, @Prm2)

Comment: Please ask only a single question per question.

Comment: And I have removed the SQL Server tag as you don't need a SQL Server expert for this...

Comment: As per my knowledge - I read it somewhere - "@" must be there when the parameter is OUT type. That's why it is there and not with the other. But I may be wrong on that.

I think this one needs somebody who both understand Java and SQL Server.

Comment: @DaleK I don't think it is worth to duplicate this just asking these questions separately:

- Do you have any idea how can I make it working?
- The second question is if I can make it working, how can I get the value of the output variable Prm2?

That just does not make any sense.

Comment: They are totally different questions and each has a totally different answer... combining them doesn't make sense... well it does to you, but it doesn't to future readers of the question - keep in mind questions asked and answered here are intended to be useful to people for years to come.